# Ansible: how do I avoid code repetitions with file src and with_first_found?

Tags: loops, ansible, repeat

I have several dozen copy actions that do the same dance to find an appropriate file based on the following config file storage hierarchy (can't change it):

```
{{role_path}}/file.name.{hostname}
{{role_path}}/file.name
/config/current/file.name.{hostname}
/config/current/file.name
/config/legacy/file.name.{hostname}
/config/legacy/file.name
```

Is there a way to avoid repeating the whole with_first_found clause for every config file as in the following?

```
- name: Copy /etc/file.name
  copy:
    src: "{{item}}"
    dest: "/etc/file.name"
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
  with_first_found:
    - files:
      - files/etc/file.name.{{inventory_hostname}}
      - files/etc/file.name
      paths:
        - "{{ role_path }}"
        - /config/current
        - /config/legacy
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract the tasks to a separate file and [loop over `include` using `loop_control`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#loops-and-includes-in-2-0) in outer loop to avoid conflict in `item` variable.